# Sum by month and then by month and category formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

[Cross-post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/docs/-7UzBRc2DhQ/iKQVhGPuDAAJ)

I've been trying to figure this out for weeks. It's a spreadsheet to help people understand their spending habits.

They enter their monthly expenses on one sheet, and the other calculates what they spent in a month total, and what they spent by each category each month.

Comment: Welcome. It's not clear what are you asking. Do you have a problem with a formula?

Comment: I keep trying different formulas but I can't find one that works.

Comment: I'm trying to get the amounts entered on sheet 1 (Expenses Breakdown 2018) to auto fill into sheet 3 (Month by Month Comparison). Where columns E4:R1000 are summed and entered into the sheet 3, C3, if they occurred in Jan, etc for each month.

Comment: Then to have them break down a little more in C18 to be sum by categories "dining out', "gas", etc, by month, indicated in column A4:A on sheet one... and etc for each category.

Answer (score 1):

this is how you SUM by month: **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NDJ1JDNvWEUZ6GjPFqvif9M_MzIxWZPy5pCYqWUDx1w/edit?usp=sharing)**

[image]

for the 2nd part, you first need to build some matrix where a category will be assigned to individual expenses because, at the current state, spreadsheet cant tell that `TELUS CABLE` is considered to be in `Cable` category. and only then, just after the categorization of expenses, you will be able to call for the right data to be broken down as you desire it.